# How do I test if a cell in OpenOffice Calc contains #N/A?

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

I'm using the `VLOOKUP` function to lookup values in a column based upon a search query. But since it's not a given that a value always exists for my search parameter, sometimes `VLOOKUP` returns `#N/A`.

**How do I write an `IF` function that tests if `VLOOKUP` returns `#N/A`?**

I've read somewhere that `#N/A` is just a text string, so I've obviously tried:

```
=IF(B1="#N/A";"Not found";B1)
```

But with no luck. So maybe it's not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just had the exact same question and [found this page about openoffice functions](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/office_guides/openoffice_calc_user_guide/openoffice_calc_Informational_functions.html).

There is a function ISNA(value) which should do the trick. In your example, the following should work:

```
=IF(ISNA(B1);"Not found";B1)
```

In my case, I wanted to check whether a cell is empty or not, this is done by `ISBLANK(value)`, just for the record.

Answer (score 5):

I always use "IFERROR" in these cases. I like everything to be pretty, so unless I'm debugging my spreadsheet, I almost always throw an "IFERROR" at the beginning of all my formulas. It will return your "else value" if the function errors, otherwise it will return the normal function value.

> =IFERROR( VLOOKUP(xxxxx) , "Not Found" )

Comment: ...but this [is not available in OpenOffice](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=92677).

Comment: Just for the record, LibreOffice has implemented IFERROR since 4.0